# R - plot normal X axis for time series

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I have a time series data in an hourly format.

```
Time    traffic
6/7/2005 7:00   56718587433
6/7/2005 8:00   76456162968
6/7/2005 9:00   82534038485
6/7/2005 10:00  88796995092

 ...

7/28/2005 10:00 51528036132
7/28/2005 11:00 69610584123
7/28/2005 12:00 76364975533
7/28/2005 13:00 81281257078
```

To plot this time series what I do is the following:

```
data<-read.csv("my_file.csv")
data<-ts(data[,2],frequency = 24*365, start=c(2005,6,7,7))
plot(data, xlab="Date", ylab = "Value")
```

And this is the plot I'm getting: 
[image: time series plot]

My question is how can I get normal x- axis values in my figure? (i.e. with `6-2005` `7-2005` or even in a daily format like `7-6-2005` `10-6-2005` etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with xts directly on your original dataframe instead of using ts (the following figure shows how it looks on a randomly generated data):

```
data <- data.frame(Time=seq(strptime('6/7/2005 7:00', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'), strptime('6/7/2006 7:00', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'), 3600), traffic=rnorm(8761, 56718587433, 100000))

head(data)
        Time     traffic
1 2005-06-07 07:00:00 56718605033
2 2005-06-07 08:00:00 56718675864
3 2005-06-07 09:00:00 56718662521
4 2005-06-07 10:00:00 56718525435
5 2005-06-07 11:00:00 56718604095
6 2005-06-07 12:00:00 56718411539

class(data$Time)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 

library(xts)
data <- xts(data$traffic, as.POSIXct(data$Time, format="%m%d%Y %H:%M"))
plot(data, major.format = "%m-%d-%Y", xlab="Date", ylab = "Value")
```

[image]

Comment: This is the error I get:

`Error in if (on == "years") {: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

Comment: you are using the original data right? not the one after converting to ts format? updated the post with the randomly generated data of the same format as your original data. Make sure that the Time variable has the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the date format is numeric? check typeof(Time). Perhaps you have to transform it:

```
 as.date(x, format = "%m-%d-%Y")
```